# Assembly 8086 logic block adressing to CHS conversion error

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am activly working on a custom OS, just for fun, you know...
I have already written a boot loader and tested it and i have also added some custom intrrupts by overriding the IVT, this is actually most of my kernel.

I recently migarated from a usb flash drive functioning as a floppy disk to a virtual hard drive, because i want to implement the FAT16 filesystem.
In order to do so, i placed my mbr in an active partition placed in sector 2048(LBA).

My extended boot loader is placed in sector 2049 i try to load it using sector 2048.
I tried loading it using int 13h and i keep getting a sector full of zeros. I added code to print the sector it reads and thats how i found out about it.

Printing sector 1 of the hard drive actually works for me, and i have no idea why, i used an online tool to convert 2049 LBA to C-0 H-33 S-34, could someone confirm this please?

This is my code (I am using nasm syntax):

```
[BITS 16]   ;Tells the assembler that its a 16 bit code
[ORG 0x7C00]    ;Origin, tell the assembler that where the code will

jmp Bootstrap               ; JMP to boot strapper
OEM: DB 0x90,"ASSOS1.0"     ; OEM ID
BytesPerSector: dw 0x200    ; number of bytes per sector (512 in decimal)
SectorsPerCluster: db 0x80  ; number of sectors per cluster (128 in decimal       meaning each file is 64kb min)
ReservedSectors: dw 0x5     ; number of sectors before first FAT
NumberOfFATS: db 0x1        ; number of FATS
RootEntries: dw 0x200       ; ???
SmallSectors: dw 0x0        ; because there are more than 60000~ sectors on this drive this is zerod
MediaIdentifier: db 0xF8    ; describes what kind of media has been inserted, meaning a phisical drive
SectorsPerFAT: dw 0x100 ; number of sectors in FAT (256 decimal)
SectorsPerTrack: dw 0x003F  ; number of physical sectors in each physical track (63) 522 tracks in total
NumberOfHeads: dw 0x00FF    ; number of heads in the drive (255) 
HiddenSectors: dd 0x800     ; number of sectors before boot sector (2048 because its a virtual something)
LargeSectors : dd 0x007FE800; number of sectors in drive 0x007D9000 (8382464 in decimal)
PhysicalDriveNumber: db 0x80; thats the physical drive number, here it is set to the 3rd hard disk 
Reserved: db 0              ; ??
ExtendedBootSignitu: db 0x29; ??                                                                    128*(actual cluster number-2)   +256        +1          +32             +2048
ValumeSerialNumber: dd 0xE47FD613; Unique number given to drive so it would be easily recognized   (cluster zise in sector      | FAT length | mbr | root dir length | hidden sectors)
ValumeLabel: db "AssOs Drive";Name of valume
FAT16: db "FAT16   "        ; name of file system
Bootstrap:
mov ah,0                    ; initilize video mode
mov al,3                    ; initilize video mode
int 10h                     ; initilize video mode

mov ah, 2                   ; read sector
mov al, 1                   ; read sector
mov ch, 0                   ; read sector
mov cl, 00100010b           ; read sector (34 decimal)
mov dh, 33                  ; read sector      the error is somewhere  here!!!
mov dl, 0x80                ; read sector
mov bx, intSec              ; read sector
int 13h
jc error


mov si, intSec              ; setup the printing
print:
lodsb                       ; load si to al
cmp al,'`'                  ; test if end of input
je end
mov ah,9                    ; print char
mov bh,0                    ; print char
mov bl,0x24                 ; print char
mov cx,1                    ; print char
int 10h                     ; print char
xor ax,ax
int 16h
xor bx,bx
xor cx,cx
xor dx,dx
mov ax,0x0300               ; read curser position
int 10h                     ; read curser position
mov ax,0x0200               ; set curser position
xor bx,bx
inc dx                      ; set curser position
int 10h                     ; set curser position
jmp print

error:
mov al,ah
mov ah,9                    ; print char
mov bh,0                    ; print char
mov bl,0x24                 ; print char
mov cx,1                    ; print char
int 10h                     ; print char
mov al,ah
xor ax,ax
int 16h

end:
jmp $
TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; make sure the 510th byte has been reached (this   is boot signiture of mbr)
DW 0xAA55                 ; signiture of boot loader
intSec db "This is test!",'`'
```

Comment: The MBR can only be at LBA 0. The first sector of a partition is the VBR (volume boot record). Partitions normally start on cylinder boundaries, so the first partition would normally be at cylinder 1, head 0, sector 1.

Comment: I will try that and update later, thanks

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, that didnt work, do you know how translate lba to chs in general?

Comment: The formula is easy to find: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing#CHS_conversion But I don't know what geometry your virtual drive is using or where your first partition actually begins. A potential problem is that if your drive is over 504 MB then the BIOS geometry would necessarily be different than the ATA geometry as reported by the drive itself. If it's over 7.5 GB then it's not possible to use the BIOS CHS functions to address the entire drive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector#Heads You probably should use LBA addressing for drives over 504 MB.